# Android: Use com.github.appintro.AppIntro and navigation Graph together

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navgraph

**Snapshot**:
I've got a project that is split up into multiple modules.
I have a single Application app where fragments and functionality are split into different modules.
Additionally to MainActivity I now have the AppIntro Activity. The module containing the MainActivity has a Gradle reference to the AppIntroActivity module.

**Task**:
From one of my slide, I need to navigate to a specific fragment (within the MainActivity).

**Problem**:
I can't send an Intent to the MainActivity (because the reference already goes the other way).

My Idea is therefore to reference a module that contains a navgraph that knows the way to the desired fragment.

**Implementation**:

- Setup Gradle file with reference to "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx" as well as the module containing the navigation graph. -> Check
- Add the FragmentContainerView into the activity_onboarding.xml -> Check:

  ```
   <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
       android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
       android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:defaultNavHost="true"
       app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_onboarding" />
  ```
- Setup the navgraph ("nav_graph_onboarding.xml"):

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/nav_graph.xml"
       app:startDestination="@id/appIntroFragment">

       <fragment
           android:id="@+id/appIntroFragment"
           android:name="com.github.appintro.AppIntroFragment"
           android:label="AppIntroFragment" />

       <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_login" />
   </navigation>
  ```

First, everything looks good. The onboarding layout opens and I can navigate through it.

The Problem if this implementation is that the onClickListener (on buttons) within the slides don't react anymore. If I remove the "androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView" everything works fine.

**Question**: How can I use the AppIntro and the navigation graph together?
Is it possible at all, or do I need a completely different approach?